# After form data is passed into aspx page and saved, how do your return to previous page without postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with html controls in JavaScript on one aspx page. When I click submit it posts data to another aspx page through the form. After the data is saved to Database, how can I return to previous page with the form? Right now the page stops on the aspx page where the form data is passed after it is saved.

Form (There is more html controls but i just posted the basics) -

```
    function ShowUploadFileDialog(CampaignId) {

        var html = '';
        var div = '#UploadFileDialog';

        checkForId(div);

        $(div).dialog({
            width: '585px',
            height: 'auto',
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "fade", //puff
            hide: "fade", //clip
            // zIndex: 3999,
            position: "fixed top+80",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            modal: true,
            close: function (event, ui) {
                // Remove all items first
            }
        });


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'CampaignsTest.aspx/LoadFiles',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                CampaignId: CampaignId
            }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                $("<img src='./Images/Logos/icon_pdf.gif'/>").prependTo("#UploadFileDialog_File");
                var obj = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                var html = '';
                html += ' <form id="CampaignUploadForm" action="UploadCampaignFile.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
                html += ' <div>';
                html += ' <div id="UploadFileDialog_Upload">';
                html += ' <br /><br />';
                html += ' <fieldset style="width: 535px; border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;">';
                html += ' <legend style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; margin: -22px 0 0 -11px;">Upload Document</legend><span style="color: Red; font-size: 10px; float: right; font-family: Arial;"> *Must be PDF File!</span>';
                html += ' <table id="uploadTable">';
                html += ' <br />';
                html += ' <tr>';
                html += ' <td align="right">';
                html += ' <span Style="color: #666666; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial">Upload File: </span>';
                html += ' </td>';
                html += ' <td>';
                html += ' <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" name="FileUpload1" accept="application/pdf" class="pointer"/>';
                html += ' </td>';
                html += ' </tr>';
                html += ' <tr>';
                html += ' <td align="right">';
                html += ' <span style="color: #666666; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial">Change File Name: </span>';
                html += ' </td>';
                html += ' <td>';
                html += ' <input type="text" id="txtTitleName" name="txtTitleName" style="width: 300px;"/>';
                html += ' </td>';
                html += ' </tr>';
                html += ' <tr>';
                html += ' <td align="right">';
                html += ' <span style="color: #666666; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial">Document Type: </span>';
                html += ' </td>';
                html += ' <td>';
                html += ' <input type="text" id="txtFileType" name="txtFileType" style="width: 150px;"/>';
                html += ' </td>';
                html += ' </tr>';
                html += ' <tr>';
                html += ' <td align="right">';
                html += ' </td>';
                html += ' <td class="style15">';
                html += ' <input id="btnUpload" value="Submit" type="submit" name="btnUpload" class="pointer buton white regular" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10px;"/> &nbsp&nbsp';
                html += ' </td>';
                html += ' </tr>';
                html += ' </table>';
                html += ' </fieldset>';
                html += ' </div>';
                html += ' <div id="UploadFileDialog_File">';
                html += '<table id="uploadPDFT" class="tablesorter">';
                html += '<thead>';
                html += '<tr style="color:white">';
                html += '<th align="center"></th><th align="center">Document Name</th><th align="center">Document Type</th><th align="center">Date Uploaded</th><th></th>';
                html += '</tr></thead>';

                if (obj.Files.length > 0) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < obj.Files.length; i++) {

                        html += "<tr>";
                        html += '<td align="center"><img src="./Images/Logos/icon_pdf.gif"/></td><td align="center">' + obj.Files[i].Name + '</td><td align="center">' + obj.Files[i].Type + '</td><td align="center">' + obj.Files[i].DateCreated + '</td>';
                        html += '<td align="right"><div class="bootstrap"><div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Options<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="pull-right dropdown-menu pointer" style="font-size: 11px;">';
                        html += '<li class="bsbi"><a onclick="DownloadFile(' + obj.Files[i].Id + ')">Open</a></li>';
                        if (obj.RoleType == 3) {
                            if (obj.Files[i].StatusCode == 0)
                                html += '<li class="bsbi"><a onclick="DeleteFile(' + obj.Files[i].Id + ')">Remove</a></li>';
                            if (obj.Files[i].StatusCode == 1)
                                html += '<li class="bsbi"><a onclick="RestoreFile(' + obj.Files[i].Id + ')">Restore</a></li>';
                        }
                        else if (obj.RoleType == 1 && obj.Files[i].RoleType == 1) {
                            html += '<li class="bsbi"><a onclick="DeleteClientFile(' + obj.Files[i].Id + ')">Delete</a></li>';
                        }
                        html += '</ul></div></div></td>';
                        html += "</tr>";

                    }

                }
                else {
                    html += "<tr>";
                    html += '<td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;"> A media plan is not available yet. Please check back later. </td>';
                    html += "</tr>";
                }
                html += "</table>";
                html += ' </div>';
                html += ' <input id="hfCampaignID" type="hidden" name="hfCampaignID"/>';
                html += ' <br /><br /><br />';
                html += ' </div></form>';


                $(div).html(html);
                $(div).dialog("open");
                $('#CampaignUploadForm').on('submit', function (e) { //use on if jQuery 1.7+
                    var data = $("#CampaignUploadForm :input").serializeArray();
                    console.log(data); //use the console for debugging, F12 in Chrome, not alerts
                    return;
                });
                $("#hfCampaignID").val(CampaignId);
            }
        });
    }
```

Second Aspx page with the Save Method

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string campaign_id = Request.Form["hfCampaignID"];
        string FileType = Request.Form["txtFileType"];
        string TitleName = Request.Form["txtTitleName"];
        HttpPostedFile file = (HttpPostedFile)Request.Files["FileUpload1"];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, file.ContentLength);

        using (CmsInterface.Cms lCms = new CmsInterface.Cms())
        {
            int CampaignID = int.Parse(campaign_id);
            Entities.File MyFiles = new Entities.File();
            MyFiles.FileData = buffer;
            MyFiles.Title = TitleName;
            MyFiles.FileName = file.FileName;
            MyFiles.FileSize = buffer.LongLength;
            MyFiles.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            MyFiles.FileType = FileType;
            MyFiles.UploadedByUserId = CmwSession.UserId;

            lCms.AddFileToCampaign(MyFiles, CampaignID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: isn't *"After form data is passed into aspx page and saved"* the postback? I guess what you're looking for is ajax.

Comment: yea, what i need is for the page not to refresh and return to the previous point with the submitted data

Comment: Then you simply need to post the data to the server using ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: The data already posted successfully, but I just need to redirect to the previous aspx page where the form came from without refreshing the page.

Comment: Right, that's EXACTLY what ajax does. If you don't stop posting it the way you are doing it and use ajax instead, it won't stop refreshing the page.

Comment: The form is already inside an ajax call. The form is part of the success.

Comment: Then you aren't making much sense... can you provide more code?

Comment: yea sure sorry about the confusion i will add the full function above

Comment: After the form is submitted, I need the page to return back to this dialog inside the function

Comment: So you're creating a dialog, populating it with a form, then when the form is submitted you're uploading a file. When the upload is complete, you want to return to the page with the dialog without refreshing, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want it to return to the page with the open dialog so the client can see the submitted file.

Comment: I'd suggest using one of the many existing file upload plugins, otherwise you'll have to deal with the cross-browser issues of ajax uploading files. The alternative is to have your form target= a hidden iframe, then listen for the load event of the iframe to know when it is complete.

Comment: I rather not use a plugin and use an iframe. I just add the iframe in the form and use the id of the iframe as the target?

Comment: The iframe doesn't have to be inside the form, but yes.

Comment: sorry for all the questions. If I am using the iframe and the file is being submitted successfully but I wont see be able to see the uploaded file unless the page is refreshed?

Comment: Once it's uploaded, you can make it visible by adding an image element to your page with a src= that targets the newly uploaded image.